# Commas in decimal disappear when stored in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, decimal

In my database, I have a column `price decimal(8,2)`.

My model:

```
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

Then, for example if I say a price is 10,10 or 10.10, it will be stored as 1010, it removes the comma or dot.

How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: How are you saving it in db? 10.10 is not the same as 1010 so there must be something translating 10.10 to 1010 incorrectly

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is happening? What locale does you C# code run under, and what locale is set for your database?

Comment: Spanish in both.
Im using entity framework

Comment: why do not multiply by 100 before inserting in db and divide by 100 after retrieving the value

Comment: because if I insert 10, it is stored as 10.00, not 1000

Answer (score 0):

Writing these lines on Startup.cs in configure method fixed it.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();

customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```